# Why do I get unexpected token 'o'?

Tags: javascript, rhomobile

Why do I get unexpected token 'o' for this piece of code?

```
Rho.ORM.addModel(function(model) {
    model.modelName('Todo');
    model.property('task','string');
    model.property('completed','boolean');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the [ORM JavaScript API](http://docs.rhomobile.com/api/OrmModel) you need to include in your html pages the file **rhoapi-modules.js**.

This is usually included in the layout.erb of your project.

Pay attention that this file is platform dependent. The system is usually generating the correct version automatically when you build your project. If you're using it on an hybrid application, you can take a look at the [relevant documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/guide/webapps#using-rhomobile-js-apis).

Comment: Yes I do have it included. The error appears on Chrome's Dev Tools. But not on the Web Inspector with RhoSimulator. But it works none the less.